# How to build a trait for generic RDD operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

I am trying to build a `trait` which would implement generic helping method for a type of `RDD` I have.

For instance:

```
abstract class MyClass(name: String) {
   final def getName: String = name
}

trait MyTrait[T <: MyClass] {
     def myMethod(
        input: RDD[T],
        something: String
     ): RDD[T] = {
        input.filter(_.getName != something)
     }

     def otherExample(
         inputA: RDD[(T, String)],
         inputB: RDD[(T, Int)]
     ): RDD[(T, (String, Int)] = {
         inputA
            .keyBy(_._1.getName)
            .join(inputB....)
            ...
     }
}
```

But I am getting weird errors such as

```
 value mapValues is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T, String)]
[error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value mapValues'?
```

I tried to add `ClassTag` in the generic class `T` but I couldn't find the right syntax as `[T <: MyClass : ClassTag]` or `[T : MyClass : ClassTag]` did not work.

Thanks !

Comment: As a side note: instead of defining methods like `getName`, you can just mark `name: String` with `val`.

Comment: oh ! I had no idea that was what `val` was doing ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix my problem.

I did not realize but the issue was only coming from `mapValues`.

It was caused by the fact that `T` was not a `ClassTag`.

To solve the issue, I added `(implicit ct: ClassTag[T])` to the method where I was using `mapValues` and that solved it.